# how to add space in the input after focus?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

The purpose is to add space after executing focus on an input which have an id = "editor".

```
let editor = document.getElementById("editor") as HTMLElement;
editor.focus();
// here I want to add &nbsp; on the focused HTMLElement "body"
```

I try to dispatch a KeyboardEvent to add space or any letter but this didn't worked.

```
editor.dispatchEvent(new KeyboardEvent('keypress',{'key':'a'}))
```

Comment: What kind of element is `editor`? Is it an input or a div or a span?
Generally you could use the [`focus event`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/focus_event) and then adjust the value/text, which is inside the editor element.

Comment: it is an input which have an id = "editor" , the focus event was executed successfully .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try below code:

```
editor.addEventListener('focus', function(event){
   if(!event.target.value){
       editor.value = ' '
   }
})
```

Comment: I execute the code inside an angular service so after `editor.focus( )` I want to add that space

Comment: It is a general Javascript event listener and it means when your editor element focused the callback function will be fired

Comment: Thank you but it doesn't work for me for now

Comment: Please share your template and component

Answer (score 0):

If it's angular then just this

```html
<input type="text" (focus)="$any($event.target).value += ' '">
<input type="text" (focus)="$any($event.target).value = $any($event.target).value + ' '">
```

Should work.
(Use the second one if the first one fails)